# When a asp.net button is clicked, add #button to the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Using jquery, when a button is clicked (server side), I want to append #button to the url.

This will only be used when there is validation errors, I want the browser to scroll to the bottom where the button is.

I already tried MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback but it doesn't work here since the validation  rows are made visible upon clicking the button.

**Update**
**actually clicking the button does a server side post first, so not sure this will work?**

Comment: Does it have to be an <asp:Button /> or can it be a <Button /> or <input type="Button" /> instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you've to fix an ugly asp.net bug, related to a js function (scrollTo) registered for MantainScrollPositionOnPostback.

A quick fix that worked for me is to redefine this function:

```
window.scrollTo = function(x, y) {
    return true;
}
```

Of course setting MantainScrollPositionOnPostback="true".